# ASP.NET session expires after 2:30

Tags: asp.net, .net, windows-7, iis-7, timeout

I have troubleshooted this for days now. The code is external. We are installing it on our system.

### OS: Windows 7

Problem: when visiting the site for the first time, it takes about 2min30sec to compile and then it throws error "You session has timed out". Interesting thing is, it loads part of the webpage, the header part.

### Other problems:

When I compile this code in Visual Studio, it does not compile (and I think it should). I get these errors

```
Error   1   Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.UI.WebControls, Version=1.0.2.226, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.  C:\Users\--\Documents\HDWeb\CoreTabStrip.ascx   1    

Error   2   Could not load type 'Excelergy.Web.HD.cEditServicePeriodTab'.   C:\Users\--\Documents\HDWeb\EditServicePeriodTab.aspx   2
```

### Possible solutions

1. I looked at [this solution](http://brianseekford.com/index.php/2009/11/23/asp-net-state-server-wont-start-on-windows-7-64-bit-file-is-missing/) which says aspnet_state.exe path can be wrong in registry and that could be the problem. It turned out to be true. This file was missing from my .net2.xxxx framework so I added it the problem is not solved.
2. I tried to download [iWebControls.msi](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=13807) to take care of the above compile errors. Turn out that file is not compatible with Window 7 and wont install.
3. I tried to trace the code but ofcourse I cann't because the code does not compile in the first place.

### Real Question

Does anyone know how can I address this issue? I already look into IIS, Application pool. Change different setting but it just times out all the time. What could be the issue.

Could it just be Windows 7 specific issue (Windows 7 + .net 2.xxxx)

Answer (score 1):

Probably the application pool running the the Recycle at 2:30

uncheck this on right click application pool> > properties > Recycling tab -> "Recycle worker processes at the following times"

Comment: +1 for idea but it did not work. The above link should be Right click on Application Pool > Recycling > ...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that you are using `in-proc session state` (the default).

This might hep you. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx and this one http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725820%28WS.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The other answers should cover everything there is to cover when it comes to sessions as far as settings are concerned - I think the only item missing is for you to check what the session timeout value is in web.config - and of course inconsistencies - re: if its **not** inproc then its either state server or sql (so of course you must have either for sessions to work).

The only other place to check would be source code (not settings). Check the code for any Session.Abandon commands or similar (re: sessions are set, removed, etc.). It may not have anything to do with settings at all and is controlled somewhere (else) in code.

You can already see an issue with that abnormal load time (initial or not) so its a sign to dig into code....